# bxslider images with different widths

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I'm trying to use the bxslider with images of different sizes that I'd like to be the same height and different widths. I'd like to have a carousel like the examples on http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified. These examples work fine, however, I have images that are 300, 400, and 500 pixels wide, each with different heights that are scaled to the same height of 400px. I do not want to resize the width of the image so they are the same or crop it. How do I use bxslider with images of different widths?

If this cannot be done using bxslider, then does a jquery plugin already exist for this behavior?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GdD52/2/

```
<ul class="slider1">
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/140x130&text=FooBar1"/></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x115&text=FooBar2"/></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/130x160&text=FooBar3"/></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/145x142&text=FooBar4"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: try **[this](http://bxslider.com/options)**, the `responsive` part

Comment: jsfiddle added to description.

Comment: it goes 2 slides per event. was that suppose to happen?

Comment: @cr0ss - no, jsfiddle is updated. http://jsfiddle.net/GdD52/2/

Comment: how do you imagine the result will be ? is all your problem centering the image ?

Comment: Looking through the source code of `bxslider.js`, it doesn't support this kind of behaviour, you'd have to rework the code to allow it.

Comment: @ProllyGeek the result like the top carousel (same height, different widths) in the jsfiddle with the addition that the current/active slide is centered.

Comment: as already pointed out, this application is just not built to **center** anything. You would have an *easier* time building your own.

Comment: Is there another plugin that already exists that solves this problem?

Comment: How many images do you have? and is the total a multiple of 3?

Comment: @TimSPQR, it isn't always a multiple of 3. The number of images is variable. There could be 2, 3, 5, 8, 20, etc images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my love for web galleries I thought to write a little script to create an infinite scrolling gallery with images of different width: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/Smz34/) 
I am aware that your wish was to change the Gallery bxslider but this solution seems acceptable
I think that bxslider Gallery does not give you this possibility
As you can see in my fiddle there is a gallery with images with differnt widths.
The script is just an example and it can be improved if you vote my answer I will improve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var wid=0;
    var maskWidth=0;
    var arr=[];
    $('#images img').each(function(i){
        wid+=parseInt($(this).attr('data-width'));
        arr.push($(this).attr('data-width'));
        if(i<3){maskWidth+=parseInt($(this).attr('data-width'));}
        });
    //set container width = 3* mor larger image
    var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, arr )*3;
    $('#container').css('width',biggest+'px');
    //set mask width= width of first 3 images
    $('#mask').css({'width':(maskWidth+36)+'px'});
    //set images width=width of all images
    $('#images').css({'width':wid+'px'});
    //set attribute data-last on thirdi image
    $('#images img:eq(2)').attr('data-pos','last');



    //next and prev click are differnent for the position of image div
    $('.next').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var widthx=$('#mask').width();
        var next=parseInt($('#images').find('img[data-pos="last"]').next('img').attr('data-width'))+12;
        $('#images').find('img[data-pos="last"]').next('img').attr('data-pos','last');
        $('#images').find('img[data-pos="last"]:first').removeAttr('data-pos');
        var ind=$('#images').find('img[data-pos="last"]').index()+1;
        var collection=$('#images').find('img').slice(ind-3,ind);
        var newWidth=0;
         $(collection).map( function( i, element ) {
             newWidth+= parseInt($(element).data( 'width' )+12);
         });
         var diff=widthx-newWidth;  
         var delta=parseInt(next)+(diff);
         $('#images').animate({'left':'-='+(delta)+'px'},1000 );
         $('#mask').animate({'width':(newWidth)+'px'},1000,function(){
             $('img:first').appendTo('#images');
             $('#images').css({'left':'0px'});
        });
    });

    $('.prev').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var widthx=$('#mask').width();
        $('img:last').prependTo('#images');
        var largh=parseInt($('img:first').attr('data-width'))+12;
        $('#images').css({'left':largh*-1+'px'});
        var collection=$('#images').find('img').slice(0,3);
        var newWidth=0;
         $(collection).map( function( i, element ) {
             newWidth+= parseInt($(element).data( 'width' )+12);
         });
         $('#mask').animate({'width':newWidth+'px'},1000);
         $('#images').animate({'left':'+='+largh+'px'},1000);
         $('#images img').removeAttr('data-pos');
         $('img:nth-child(3)').attr('data-pos','last');
    });

})
</script>
```

Since i like this question in this other [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/qLM9e/1/) you'll find another improved version of this gallery with the buttons for browse images in group of tree
Again, the script coul be improved the next step could be:
N1 make the gallery responsive
N2 transform the scipt in a jQuery plugin

Answer (score 2):

```
#bx-wrapper img {
    width: auto !important
}
```

But I am having issues with touch scrolling. So I am going to try [owlCarousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/).

Comment: Thx for recommending the Owl Carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm just going to throw this rudimentary code as an idea - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j82Y4/1/).

It's a start, just tell me what changes you would want. It's not perfect, because one of the pictures is too wide, but given your criteria, that would be easy to fix. What I did is do most of the styling in CSS, and just float the pictures through each div.

JS

```
var first, second, third;

var numphotos = $('.hidden img').length;

if(numphotos === 0)
  {
    first = 0; second = 0; third = 0;
  }
if(numphotos === 1)
  {
    first = 0; second = 1; third = 0;
    putphotos(first, second, third);
  }
if(numphotos === 2)
  {
    first = 0; second = 1; third = 2;
    putphotos(first, second, third);
  }
if(numphotos > 2)
  {
    first = 0; second = 1; third = 2;
    putphotos(first, second, third);
  }
$('.forward').on('click', function(){
  first = first+1;
  second = second+1;
  third = third+1;
  putphotos(first, second, third);
  if(third == numphotos)
  {
   first = 1; second = 2; third = 3;
   putphotos(first, second, third);
  }
});

function putphotos(first, second, third)
{
$( '.minishowme:nth-child(1)' ).html('');
$( '.minishowme:nth-child(2)' ).html('');
$( '.minishowme:nth-child(3)' ).html('');

$('.hidden img:nth-child(' + first + ')').clone().appendTo( '.minishowme:nth-child(1)' );
$('.hidden img:nth-child(' + second + ')').clone().appendTo( '.minishowme:nth-child(2)' );
$('.hidden img:nth-child(' + third + ')').clone().appendTo( '.minishowme:nth-child(3)' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have a carousel like the examples on
>   `http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified`. These examples work
>   fine...

The example does not *center* slides. It shows 3 slides aligned to the *left up* corner.

To display images with different height and width you should align them to the same width

- and either vertically center at the middle - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tK9Wa/1/
- or use overflow:hide to make same height - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6jQPg/3/