# bxSlider jQuery Plugin same Height varying Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this plugin to create a gallery of images. However, I am trying to figure out how to set the images so that it is the same Height but with varying Widths. In [bxslider images with different widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962985/bxslider-images-with-different-widths), it provides a solution, but it sets a fixed width for the images in the gallery, thus not making it responsive anymore.

Another part is how to make the background of the bxSlider transparent, so it shows the background of my html. my Code is below, thanks for any help given.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="back_to_story">
        <a href="ourstory.html">Our Story</a>
    </div> <!-- back_to_story -->

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div id="navigationmenu">
    </div>

    <p id="time">
    </p>

    <div class="main_container">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="before">
           <p><span id="prev"></span></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8" id="content" style="background:#666">
      <!--       GALLERY -->
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="assets/slides/image1.png"></li>
                <li><img src="assets/slides/image2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="assets/slides/image3.jpg"></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="after">        
            <p><span id="next"></span></p>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager:false,
        nextSelector: '#next',
        prevSelector: '#prev',
        nextText: 'NEXT',
        prevText: 'PREV'
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    padding:50px;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#before, #after{
    background-color: red;
}

#prev, #next{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

#content{
    min-height: 100%
}

.bxslider{
    top:-5px;
    left:-5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport 
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    left: 0;

        -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
        -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);

    height:100%;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bxslider images with different widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962985/bxslider-images-with-different-widths)

Comment: i've seen that, but it doesnt provide a solution with the plugin, it just gives a whole new code. I'm trying to see if it could be resolved with the plugin. thanks

Comment: It's fairly apparent from that and the examples that bxSlider doesn't accommodate varying widths. You could use the images as backgrounds and `background-size: cover` if cropping is tolerable.

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your quick response. Any idea which jquery plugin would accomodate varying widths? thanks for your help

Comment: http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/merge.html Be aware that this is Owl v2.0, which is still in beta. You can easily find yourself in the v1 docs if you're not careful. I've used it with good success, though. The responsive behavior and mousewheel/swipe support makes it great for mobile.

Comment: @isherwood hi thanks for the recommendation. With the merge demo from owlcarousel would it be possible to only show one image at a time? 

Also I'm using bootstrap twitter, would you recommend the carousel from there? Thanks again for your help and advice